# Proper imap folder structure

Tags: imap, email

I want to build proper configuration for IMAP folder structure at my clients mailboxes so they can use Windows Mail or Live Mail without problems.

Can anyone tell me right config or folder structure for IMAP on my root server?, so Windows Live Mail would work ?

Now, i got structure like this, but this semms to not work. I mean, Mail program does not store /send mails/, /or trash messages/. I have changed names of the folders in IMAP configuration (Windows Mail), still no luck.

```
mailboxname/Maildir

.Trash
.Drafts
.Sent
cur
new
tmp
courierimaphieracl
courierimapkeywords

courierimapsubscribed
maildirsize
```

Answer (score 4):

Each IMAP client has their own "interpretation" of how they want to interact to what they "expect" for folders. Your best bet may be to configure each client and then use the resulting folder structure to base the setup of other account/configurations.

Unfortunately, due the the lack of uniformity between the different IMAP clients and their folder expectations/interactions, running multiple clients against a single IMAP account can be challenging in matching up the folders between the clients.